# How to make a JPQL or Criteria search query for this case

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, jpql, criteria-api

I have a class Tenure:

```
public class Tenure {
    private long minimumPeriod;
    private long maximumPeriod;

    private Period getMinimumPeriod(){
       //custom logic which converts period to long and vice versa
    }

    private Period getMaximumPeriod() {
       //custom logic which converts period to long and vice versa
    }
}
```

Period is java.time.Period, introduced in Java 8 and not yet supported atleast in MySQL so far. That's why I've to store it as long.

Now, I want to search a Tenure whose maximumPeriod is greater than some Period 'p', and minimumPeriod is less than 'p'.

I can write a CriteriaQuery like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tenure> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tenure.class);
Root<Tenure> root = criteriaQuery.from(Tenure.class);
Root<Long> minimumPeriod = root.get("minimumPeriod");
Root<Long> maximumPeriod = root.get("maximumPeriod");

Period p = // somevalue;
long pToLong = convertPeriodToLong(p);
```

Now build the criteriaQuery like this:

```
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(maximumPeriod, pToLong),criteriaBuilder.lessThan(minimumPeriod, pToLong));
```

This works. But the problem is it is dependent on the underlying implementation of my 'Tenure' class. Rather than comparing the long value of Period, I want to compare directly the 'Period'as that is what makes sense at the application layer. I have my custom logic for comparing 'Period', so no issues with that.

Is there any way I can achieve that? I don't want someone to know that Period was converted to long before storing in the database and then convert all Periods to long wherever Tenure is to be fetched from the database.

JPQL Query would also do.

Comment: You don't say what your implementation library is. But if it is hibernate there is a way to register your own value type. See section 6.4.1 on this page https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html

Comment: You are probably using a more recent version of hibernate than 3. Here is the link for the relevant section in Hibernate 4.3. This sounds like what you are looking for.
 https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-types-custom

Comment: @carbontax Thanks! I'll go through it and try to post the solution.